# Why is BrowserRouter both a Router and a Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module, react-router

Could someone explain what is happening with the double import in the below code? It sniffs of polymorphism but I don't think that is what's happening.

This is from the [ReactRouter docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route). It works, I just want to understand what's happening behind the scenes.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

<Router>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/news" component={NewsFeed}/>
  </div>
</Router>
If the location of the app is / then the UI hierarchy will be something like:<div>
  <Home/>
  <!-- react-empty: 2 -->
</div>
And if the location of the app is /news then the UI hierarchy will be:<div>
  <!-- react-empty: 1 -->
  <NewsFeed/>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not. You're importing `BrowserRouter` aliased to `Router` and `Route` both from the `react-router-dom` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not importing it "as a Router and a Route."

When you write `import { Something as Alias, SomethingElse } from 'module';` you're just [aliasing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) - in this case `module.Something` becomes `Alias`.

Equivalent code, without aliasing, would be

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

<BrowserRouter>
    ...
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Good explanation. Thank you.